# Moving the the very bottom of the file with vi

Tags: vim, vi

No, I'm not talking about vim, I'm talking about old-school vi; because in vim you can actually issue a `:bot` and it'll move to the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From command mode, type the upper case letter 'G'.

Comment: What about going back to the top of the file?

Comment: Prefix the G with a line number: 1G

Comment: Alternatively :gg will bring you to the top

Comment: Or :1 to jump specifically to line one.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Colon</kbd> to get to the `:` prompt.

Then type any integer and ENTER to jump to that line number or...

`$` to jump to the end line of the file.

Other uses of the `$` in vi are:

E.g.

```
:1,$s/foo/bar/
```

this means: take the range of lines from 1 to the end of the file (`$`) and search them (s) for 'foo' and replace them with 'bar'.

I learned `vi` back in 1989 and I still use it today!

Comment: This one makes more sense to me, because `$` is the end of the line too.